# Código da documentação do Hibernate não está claro

Tags: java, hibernate

A minha dúvida é com relação a um código que está na documentação do Hibernate. Eu simplesmente não consegui entender a notação que eles utilizaram na parte do criteria.where(). Percebam só como foi colocado: `Person_.name`. Alguém pode me explicar? Segue o trecho onde ocorre isso que eu falei:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Person> criteria = builder.createQuery( Person.class );
Root<Person> root = criteria.from( Person.class );
criteria.select( root );
criteria.where( builder.equal( root.get( Person_.name ), "John Doe" ) );

List<Person> persons = entityManager.createQuery( criteria ).getResultList();
```

Eu já tentei fazer o mesmo, mas aqui diz "Cannot be resolved to a variable", nesse trecho de código.

A documentação é recente, segue o link: [Documentação do Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria-typedquery-entity)

Comment: `Person_` é um metamodelo gerado através da classe `Person`. Veja se esse link te ajuda a entender sobre os metamodelos e como gerá-los: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html

Comment: Pois é Roque, é bem isso mesmo. Obrigado.